# views teaser read more loading to another node instead of slideshow

Tags: views, 7, nodes

I have created 5 news using teaser view and provided a read more link. when i click on read more it is pointing to another page instead of slideshow. I tried with views slideshow but ended up with nothing.

Comment: Insufficient Information: Is the read more link the one provided by Views, or something custom? Is the slideshow part of the original content/node?

Comment: The read more link is by teaser views. and slide show is not working